# Excel vba code to insert a column with consecute group of numbersexcel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 1 column, 1500 rows. I want to insert a column next to it with the next sequence 1111 skip a row then 2222 skip a row then 3333 and so until row 1500, please help with some vba code or formula, thanks

Comment: SO isn't a "code for me" site.  Please let us know what you have tried, what has/hasn't worked, etc.  Or explain a method you think would work.  Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you want after 9999 but the short trip will be:

write 1111 (the cell you want it)
do the same for 2222
select from 1111 to the cell after 2222 and the simply autofill till the end

[image]